# Javascript executing more than one case in if else statement

Tags: javascript

I have a curious problem with some javascript.  In the following code the browser will execute more than one path in the if, else if, else if conditions.  So for example the console will log "a c" or "b c".

```
if (divs[i].row == hover_div.row && divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj)
{
    console.log("a");
    divs[i].obj.stop()
        .animate({'width':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false })
        .animate({'height':d_expand}, { duration:600, queue:false });
}
else if (divs[i].col == hover_div.col && divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj)
{
    console.log("b");
    divs[i].obj.stop()
        .animate({'width':d_expand}, { duration:600, queue:false })
        .animate({'height':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false });
}
else if (divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj);
{
    console.log("c");
    divs[i].obj.stop()
        .animate({'width':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false })
        .animate({'height':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false });
}
```

I've checked that the code isn't executing twice by adding a counter just outside the block. If I nest the if statements as below the whole thing works fine, but I shouldn't need to should I?

```
if (divs[i].row == hover_div.row && divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj)
{
    console.log("a");
    divs[i].obj.stop()
        .animate({'width':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false })
        .animate({'height':d_expand}, { duration:600, queue:false });
}
else {
    if (divs[i].col == hover_div.col && divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj)
    {
        console.log("b");
        divs[i].obj.stop()
            .animate({'width':d_expand}, { duration:600, queue:false })
            .animate({'height':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false });
    }
    else {
        if (divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj);
        {
            console.log("c");
            divs[i].obj.stop()
                .animate({'width':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false })
                .animate({'height':d_thin}, { duration:600, queue:false });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you made your problem curious

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
else if (divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj); // <--
```

delete the semicolon

Comment: Cheers for that.  Can't beat a careful reading of the code sometimes!

Answer (score 4):

You have a trailing semicolon on this line:

```
else if (divs[i].obj != hover_div.obj);
```

which is the same as saying:

```
else if (...) {
   // do nothing
}

{
   console.log("c");
   ...
}
```

Hence block c is always run.